# Amazon CloudFront vs. S3 --> restrict access by domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

On Amazon S3, you can restrict access to buckets by domain.

But as far as I understand from a helpful StackOverflow user, you cannot do this on CloudFront. But why? If I am correct, CloudFront only allows time-based restrictions or IP restrictions (--> so I need to know the IP's of random visitors..?) Or am I missing something?

Here is a quote from S3 documentation that suggests that per-domain restriction is possible:

---> " To allow read access to these objects from your website, you can add a bucket policy that allows s3:GetObject permission with a condition, using the aws:referer key, that the get request must originate from specific webpages. "

--> Is there a way to make this method work on CloudFront as well? Or why something like this is not available on CloudFront?

--> Is there a similar service where this is possible, easier to setup?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using CloudFront along with WAF (Web Application Firewall), you can restrict requests based on IP address, referrers, or domains.

Here is a AWS blog tutorial on restricting "hotlinking".

https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx2CSKIBS7EP1I5/How-to-Prevent-Hotlinking-by-Using-AWS-WAF-Amazon-CloudFront-and-Referer-Checkin

In this example, it prohibits requests where the `Referrer:` header does not match a specific domain.

Comment: Thanks! The article says:
"Step 1: Determine what you need to protect.
Because I have all of my static files on a separate subdomain (*static.example.com*), accessed only from example.com, I will block hotlinking for any files accessible under static.example.com that do not have a Referer ending with example.com."

--> But I will have my video files on S3 and CloudFront, with a CloudFront URL and NOT on my own static.example.com, no? So how does WAF protects my CloudFront files, when the article is talking about files being on static.example.com? What do I misunderstand?

Comment: I thought you wanted to ensure referers came from your domain. Please clarify your situation (be specific) and the criteria under which you want to protect your files.

Comment: I have my website - www.example.com - on a Hostgator shared server. I have to display 360-degree videos. The 360video player is a custom player by Pano2VR. It's a simple JS file (let's call it PLAYER.JS) that sits on my www.example.com. This JS file points directly to my MP4 files. The MP4 files are NOT on my www.example.com, but on Amazon S3, connected to CloudFront. They now have a CloudFront URL. Goal: only PLAYER.JS sitting on www.example.com can play back the CloudFront MP4 videos. Others linking to the file should get access denied. I hope it's clearer? If not  let me know. THANK YOU!

Comment: Yes, so in this case, the above example should be what you're looking for: a referrer enforcement to ensure that the referrer is only www.example.com. However, you'll want to verify that PLAYER.JS sets the `Referrer:` header when loading the videos.

Comment: Got it, great help!!

Comment: @MattHouser, where did you find the reference to restricting by domain? I wasn't able to find it anywhere.

Comment: @NaorLevi It's every part that tells you to add conditions on your WAF for the Referrer header.

Comment: @MattHouser, but If I cURL with this header I will get a success response, it's not restricted by the domain...

Comment: @NaorLevi WAF does not receive your browser history. The Referrer header is all the information WAF gets, and WAF needs to trust that the header is set properly by the browser. If allowing/denying your request using cURL with/without setting the Referral header, then it's working properly.

If you want something more "secure" than that, you'll need to investigate other methods, such as time-expired URLs.