# Limited access to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to understand access security as it relates to Amazon S3. I want to host some files in an S3 bucket, using CloudFront to access it via my domain. I need to limit access to certain companies/individuals. In addition I need to manage that access individually.

A second access model is project based, where I need to make a library of files available to a particular project team, and I need to be able to add and remove team members in an ad hoc manner, and then close access for the whole project at some point. The bucket in question might be the same for both scenarios.

I assume something like this is possible in AWS, but all I can find (and understand) on the AWS site involves using IAM to control access via the AWS console. I don't see any indication that I could create an IAM user, add them to an IAM group, give the group read only access to the bucket and then provide the name and password via `System.Net.WebClient` in PowerShell to actually download the available file. Am I missing something, and this IS possible? Or am I not correct in my assumption that this can be done with AWS?

I did find [Amazon CloudFront vs. S3 --> restrict access by domain? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718572/amazon-cloudfront-vs-s3-restrict-access-by-domain) that talks about using CloudFront to limit access by Domain, but that won't work in a WfH scenario, as those home machines won't be on the corporate domain, but the corporate BIM Manager needs to manage access to content libraries for the WfH staff. I REALLY hope I am not running into an example of AWS just not being ready for the current reality.

Comment: Please take a look on Cognito. I'm using it with multiple groups and access.

Comment: You say "I need to limit access to certain companies/individuals". How do you intend identifying/authorizing these individuals? Do you have a web application where they first login before accessing the files? Or do you intend issuing them with IAM credentials (which is not recommended outside your organization)? Similarly, how do you intend to authenticate and grant access for the project scenario? Feel free to edit your question with these details rather than answering via a comment. It will be easier to offer recommendations once we have this additional information.

Comment: @john-rotenstein I guess that depends on how I NEED to. If I can create IAM users and assign passwords I can do that manually. I guess to clarify, I am asking what is the right/best way to do this? Again, assuming that I cannot limit anything by domain, since we are talking about a Work from home scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to issue IAM User credentials (max 5000 per account), the steps would be:

- Create an **IAM User** for each user and select **Programmatic access**
- This will provide an Access Key and Secret Key that you can provide to each user
- Attach permissions to each IAM User, or put the users in an IAM Group and attach permissions to the IAM Group
- Each user can run `aws configure` on their computer (using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to store their Access Key and Secret Key
- They can then use the AWS CLI to upload/download files

If you want the users to be able to access via the Amazon S3 management console, you will need to provide some additional permissions: [Grant a User Amazon S3 Console Access to Only a Certain Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-console-access-certain-bucket/)

Alternatively, users could use a program like [CyberDuck](https://cyberduck.io/) for an easy Drag & Drop interface to Amazon S3. Cyberduck will also ask for the Access Key and Secret Key.

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks. I should then be able to automate the AWS CLI access via Powershell, as the process needs to happen regularly, and transparently to the user once set up. And the sync option may mean I don't need to write my own file map based compare. I know what I'm doing this weekend. :)

Comment: [AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/)

Answer (score 2):

Content stored in Amazon S3 is private by default. There are several ways that access can be granted:

- Use a **bucket policy** to make the entire bucket (or a directory within it) publicly accessible to everyone. This is good for websites where anyone can read the content.
- Assign permission to **IAM Users** to grant access only to users or applications that need to access to the bucket. This is typically used *within* your organization. Never create an IAM User for somebody *outside* your organization.
- Create **presigned URLs** to grant temporary access to private objects. This is typically used by applications to grant web-based access to content stored in Amazon S3.

To provide an example for pre-signed URLs, imagine that you have a photo-sharing website. Photos provided by users are private. The flow would be:

- A user logs in. The application **confirms their identity** against a database or an authentication service (eg Login with Google).
- When the user wants to view a photo, the application first **checks whether they are entitled** to view the photo (eg it is their photo). If they are entitled to view the photo, the application **generates a pre-signed URL** and returns it as a link, or embeds the link in an HTML page (eg in a `<img>` tag).
- When the user accesses the link, the browser sends the URL request to Amazon S3, which verifies the encrypted signature in the signed URL. If if it is correct and the link has not yet expired, the photo is returned and is displayed in the web browser.
- Users can also **share photos with other users**. When another user accesses a photo, the application checks the database to confirm that it was shared with the user. If so, it provides a pre-signed URL to access the photo.

This architecture has the application perform all of the logic around Access Permissions. It is very flexible since you can write whatever rules you want, and then the user is sent to Amazon S3 to obtain the file. Think of it like buying theater tickets online -- you just show the ticket and the door and you are allowed to sit in the seat. That's what Amazon S3 is doing -- it is checking the ticket (signed URL) and then giving you access to the file.

See: [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

**Mobile apps**

Another common architecture is to **generate temporary credentials** using the AWS Security Token Service (STS). This is typically done with mobile apps. The flow is:

- A user logs into a mobile app. The app sends the login details to a back-end application, which verifies the user's identity.
- The back-end app then uses AWS STS to generate **temporary credentials** and assigns permissions to the credentials, such as being permitted to access a certain directory within an Amazon S3 bucket. (The permissions can actually be for *anything* in AWS, such as launching computers or creating databases.)
- The back-end app sends these temporary credentials back to the mobile app.
- The mobile app then uses those credentials to make calls directly to Amazon S3 to access files.
- Amazon S3 checks the credentials being used and, if they have permission for the files being requests, grants access. This can be done for uploads, downloads, listing files, etc.

This architecture takes advantage of the fact that mobile apps are quite powerful and they can communicate directly with AWS services such as Amazon S3. The permissions granted are based upon the user who logs in. These permissions are determined by the back-end application, which you would code. Think of it like a temporary employee who has been granted a building access pass for the day, but they can only access certain areas.

See: [IAM Role Archives - Jayendra's Blog](https://jayendrapatil.com/tag/iam-role/)

The above architectures are *building blocks* for how you wish to develop your applications. Every application is different, just like the two use-cases in your question. You can securely incorporate Amazon S3 in your applications while maintaining full control of how access is granted. Your applications can then concentrate on the **business logic** of controlling access, without having to actually **serve the content** (which is left up to Amazon S3). It's like **selling the tickets without having to run the theater**.

You ask whether Amazon S3 is "ready for the current reality". Many of the popular web sites you use every day run on AWS, and you probably never realize it.

Comment: Thanks for that! Looks like I have a bunch of reading to do. My first concern however, is it seems like a pre-signed URL is time limited. So I can't create one for each customer and have them use to for months or years, then void it when appropriate. Am I understanding that right?
Also, your comment about S3 being "ready" makes me think I have allowed some misunderstanding. I know S3 works fine for web sites, but that is not my need. I need to control PowerShell file download of S3 hosted content, with a constantly changing mix of who is allowed access. A bit edge case.

Comment: Also, there is no "sign in" on the app. I need to provide the identifier as a file, string, etc. Something that I can store in a known location, access in my Powershell script and thus enable access. It needs to be transparent to the user after initial setup. If I can't do that, then I need to rethink a LOT more than just this, and likely it would just be too much friction to be viable for this use case.

Comment: A pre-signed URL is time-limited, yes. That way, it grants access "now", but it won't work later. It's a great way to control access. Alternatively, you could give them IAM User credentials, but this is not recommended for people outside your organisation. Frankly, it's sounding like you might be better-off using an application like Dropbox or Box.com rather than trying to build the solution yourself. Those types of services often use AWS for storage, but present higher-level applications for users.

Comment: Unfortunately Dropbox or Box, or OneDrive for that matter, just aren't options. They are fine for some things, but this would be like a movie production hosting their dailies on Dropbox so the editors have access. Never going to happen.

Comment: But, this is where I think S3 maybe isn't able to handle some of the subtleties of WfH, especially with regards to Architecture (the profession, not the software industry use of the word to mean design). And I'll need to build my own mechanism, which may still depend on S3 for storage. I was just hoping S3 allowed for something simple, like a token I could provide users, that gets handed to AWS as authentication, and that can be revoked.

Comment: Also, it occurs to me that providing IAM credentials might make sense here. In effect, these users ARE being made part of the organization temporarily. Much like a technical consultant getting domain login credentials for the duration of a project. So, let's assume that IAM credentials makes sense. Can I "pass" that credential to AWS from within a PowerShell script? Or is an IAM credential only good for logging in to the AWS dashboard?

Comment: I am finally getting back to this, and I have some more questions. I have my test bucket set up, and an IAM user who is part of an IAM group, which has the `AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess` policy attached. But I am unclear on how to configure from here. At the bucket itself, under Permissions/ACL, the only Group available is everyone, and the information popup seems to say I can only grant permissions to "S3 preassigned groups". How do I grant read only permissions to a specific bucket to specific groups? I think that will get me the control I need. THANKS!

Comment: Or is the only way to do it via Policy, and that requires writing JSON? I will admit I was hoping for check boxes. But I guess if I manage everything with groups, even a large firm would only have a limited number of groups, one for their own Work From Home staff, and some for consultants on each project. So the policy JSON wouldn't be massive. If I am missing the "easy" option, I would love to know, otherwise I will proceed to learn some policy JSON. Hopefully I can grok the minimum permissions required to allow download of a single file and sync of a bucket folder, via CLI & PowerShell.

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question for this, since it is getting off-topic and into comments so other people can't benefit from the knowledge. You should create a policy in the IAM Group that permits appropriate access only to that S3 bucket. Do not grant them ReadOnlyAccess, otherwise they will be able to read _all_ of your S3 buckets!

Comment: Thanks John. Sounds like I have a lot of reading to do, and then a new question if I am still confused.